# Делаю кнопку "Продолжить". Как сохранить состояние сцены?

Tags: ios, разработка-игр, swift, spritekit

Как можно сделать кнопку "Продолжить" в игре? я так понимаю для этого нужно сохранять состояние сцены. Пытался сохранить саму сцену в `NSUserDefaults` но не сработало.

Tекст ошибки:

> Attempt to set a non-property-list object  name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {1024, 768}} as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key Scene]

Answer (score 1):

Все объекты SpriteKit поддерживают архивирование, поэтому Apple рекомендует сохранять сцены используя [NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Articles/creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000950-SW2).